# # is automatically coming up after the URL on page load

Tags: javascript

If you visit the link http://www.feriebolig-europa.dk/ , a trailing /# will show up after the page load.

It is basically an issue of this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://p14943.atraveo.com/index.php?controller=partnerintegration&action=default&width=1080&height=1000&lg=da&cur=DKK&versionname=Spanien_landingpage"></script>
```

Which consists of 3 different javascripts. The affecting script is:

```
http://p14943.atraveo.com/website/static/js/partnerFrame.js
```

The script of the source:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener("message", function(a) {
    if (!("website" !== a.origin.substr(a.origin.length - 7) && ".atraveo.com" !== a.origin.substr(a.origin.length - 12) && ".atraveo.de" !== a.origin.substr(a.origin.length - 11) && ".atraveo-test.de" !== a.origin.substr(a.origin.length - 16)))
        if ("scrollUp" == a.data) window.location.hash = "atraveo", window.location.hash = "";
        else if ("scrollToFrame" == a.data) {
        if (a = document.getElementById(atraveoFrameId)) a = a.offsetTop, document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop =
            a : document.body.scrollTop = a
    } else document.getElementById(atraveoFrameId).style.height = a.data + "px"
}, !1);
</script>
```

The following line is the probable cause to be more specific:

```
if ("scrollUp" == a.data) window.location.hash = "atraveo", window.location.hash = "";
```

If I add:

```
window.location.href.replace('#', '');
```

with line the issue gets solved.

But, since I have no control over the 3-rd party site, I was wondering if anything could be done from my side?

Comment: Not clear what you control. Can you modify that line or not?

Comment: What is "3-rd party site" supposed to mean?

Comment: It's not clear what your "issue" is.

Comment: @charlietfl, the only script I have is the one my affiliated site provided to me:
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://p14943.atraveo.com/index.php?controller=partnerintegration&action=default&width=1080&height=1000&lg=da&cur=DKK&versionname=Spanien_landingpage"></script>
I have no control over any other scripts I mentioned in my question.

Comment: why is the hash so alarming? does page refresh properly?

Comment: Yes, page refresh is fine.
But, for some reasons, hash is quite odd to use in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try {
    //check wether it's working + initial cleanup
    history.replaceState( history.state, document.title, location.href.replace(/#$/,"") );

    //if the code didn't throw yet, add the event-listener
    addEventListener("hashchange", function(){
        var href = location.href, regex = /#$/;
        if(regex.test(href)) 
            history.replaceState( history.state, document.title, href.replace(regex, "") );
    }, false);
}catch(err){}
```

history-manipulation may be not available in some browser, that's why I wrapped the code in a try-catch-block and trigger `history.replaceState()`.

On the other hand, if this code fails in older browser, the trailing `#` may be unattractive, but it's not something crucial, that needs to be fixed at any cost.

Comment: It somehow works, but I don't want to see the appearing of the hashtag and then vanishes.

Comment: insert this snippet before the atraveo-script, maybe even in the header or at the top of the body. It has no dependencies whatsoever, so you don't have to wait for any lib to be loaded. This script should have no noticeable delay; actually if you change the hash manually you don't see any delay.

Comment: Putting the script in <head> does not resolve the issue, still shows the hash and then disappears.
"actually if you change the hash manually you don't see any delay."
--- What do you mean by that?